# Call to undefined function bootstrap_form_process() in Drupal 7 with Bootstrap 3 theme

Tags: php, drupal, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-7

Steps to reproduce:

1. Bootstrap 3, Drupal 7 Theme - latest versions
2. Edit a form
3. Change something and save it

PHP fatal error occurs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function bootstrap_form_process() in mydirectory/includes/form.inc on line 1850
```

I'm using latest version of Bootstrap Theme. It works fine with Bartik theme. Is this somehow related to https://www.drupal.org/node/2156371?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue, it was caused by the `max_input_vars` PHP setting not being high enough.

Just open your `php.ini` and set this with a high number (or higher than the one you already have set):

`max_input_vars = XXXX`

Answer (score 0):

You can debug and locate error.log to find error something like:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0
```

Just update php.ini to include and Restart the server to apply the changes:

```
 max_input_vars: To some higher value
```

By Default its 1000

Make sure to check max_input_vars value is et to some highre value using:

```
phpinfo()
```

Or Go to Admin/Reports/Status Reports to see PHP information in Drupal Portal to verify the max_input_vars newly set value

If it doesn't solve the issue

Look into avaliable posts at https://www.drupal.org/node/2156371
Update the files to include

```
 include_once(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap') . '/includes/process.inc');
```